# Permutation groups: $S_4$ and $D_4$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

Question. Determine the subgroup of $S_4$ generated by $\sigma=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$ e $\tau = (2\ 4)$. Show that $\left<\sigma, \tau\right> <S_4$ is isomorphic to the group of square symmetries.

Attempt to solve. I found that, $\left<\sigma, \tau\right>=\{e, \sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3, \tau, \sigma \circ \tau, \tau \circ \sigma, \sigma^2 \circ \tau\}$. We have that, the group of symmetries of square $D_4$ has $8$ elements. Consider the application
$$f : \left<\sigma, \tau\right> \to D_4$$
I need help defining this application and showing that there is an isomorphism.

Comment: You have already done all of the hard work.  Find elements in $D_4$ that act like $\sigma$ and $\tau$ and that will give your isomorphism.

Comment: @wavilsonferreira: Map generators of $\langle\sigma,\tau\rangle$ to generators of $D_4$.

Comment: $D_4=\{e,r_1,r_2,r_3,s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4\}$ where $r_i$ are the rotations and $s_i$ the reflections, I know that $\left<\sigma,\tau\right>$ and $D_4$ coincide as follows $\sigma=r_1,\sigma^2=r_2,...,\sigma^2 \circ \tau=s_4$. @YadatiKiran how can I do this, considering that the $D_4$ generators are $r_1$ and $s_4$, if those generators are wrong, could you tell me the correct ones?

Comment: @wavilsonferreira: Consider mapping $\sigma\mapsto a$ and $\tau\mapsto b$ where $a,b\in D_4$ such that $b^2=e=a^4$.